# How to resize and translate a masked image over a background OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, matplotlib

By doing a bit of my own googling and following [this](https://medium.com/fnplus/blue-or-green-screen-effect-with-open-cv-chroma-keying-94d4a6ab2743) tutorial I have created the python script below. It finds the most dominant (common) color in an image and replaces it with another "background" image. It basically creates a mask and places it on top of the background image. My question is how would I resize the mask and translate it. I am a complete beginner to OpenCV with Python so some code examples with explanation would go a long way :).

Here is the script:

```
import os
#from colorthief import ColorThief
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

imgDirec = "/Users/.../images"

def find_dominant_color(filename):
        #Resizing parameters
        width, height = 150,150
        image = Image.open(filename)
        image = image.resize((width, height),resample = 0)
        #Get colors from image object
        pixels = image.getcolors(width * height)
        #Sort them by count number(first element of tuple)
        sorted_pixels = sorted(pixels, key=lambda t: t[0])
        #Get the most frequent color
        dominant_color = sorted_pixels[-1][1]
        return dominant_color



filepath = "/Users/.../image.jpg" #Foreground Image
dominant_color = find_dominant_color(filepath)
#dominant_color = color_thief.get_color(quality=1)
print(dominant_color)
image = cv2.imread(filepath)
image_copy = np.copy(image)
image_copy = cv2.cvtColor(image_copy, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
lower_blue = np.array([dominant_color[0]-20, dominant_color[1]-20, dominant_color[2]-20])     ##[R value, G value, B value]
upper_blue = np.array([dominant_color[0]+20, dominant_color[1]+20, dominant_color[2]+20])
#plt.imshow(image_copy)


mask = cv2.inRange(image_copy, lower_blue, upper_blue)
#plt.imshow(mask, cmap='gray')

masked_image = np.copy(image_copy)
masked_image[mask != 0] = [0, 0, 0]
#plt.imshow(masked_image)
background_image = cv2.imread('/Users/.../background1.jpg')
background_image = cv2.cvtColor(background_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

crop_background = background_image[0:image_copy.shape[0], 0:image_copy.shape[1]]

crop_background[mask == 0] = [0, 0, 0]

#plt.imshow(crop_background)

#These Transformations do not work as intended.
newImg = cv2.resize(crop_background, (0,0), fx=2, fy=2)

height, width = masked_image.shape[:2]
quarter_height, quarter_width = height / 4, width / 4
T = np.float32([[1, 0, quarter_width], [0, 1, quarter_height]])
img_translation = cv2.warpAffine(masked_image, T, (width, height)) 


final_image = crop_background + masked_image
plt.imshow(final_image)
plt.show()
```

This is image.jpg

[image: Person against white background]

This is background1.jpg

[image]

And running the script right know I get:

[image]

I want to be able to make the person smaller and translate him around the background. How would I do this? Also, is there any way to keep the background image the original size while putting the smaller picture of the person on top? Again I am beginner (primarily an iOS Dev) so there may be a pretty obvious solution. Please enlighten me!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For answering this problem you must find two things in the code. First one is that, in which line the background cropped? This process will be in the below line

```
crop_background = background_image[0:image_copy.shape[0], 0:image_copy.shape[1]]
```

So for translating `Person` in background you must define two offsets that translate image in background. I Will do that like this:

```
x_offset=100 # translate in x-axis
y_offset=200  # translate in y-axis
crop_background = background_image[y_offset:image_copy.shape[0]+y_offset, x_offset:image_copy.shape[1]+x_offset]
```

So far we added translation feature, but how we can see the whole background instead of cropped background? for adding this feature you should overwrite `final_image` to the exact location of which we crop the image.

```
background_image[y_offset:image_copy.shape[0]+y_offset, x_offset:image_copy.shape[1]+x_offset]=final_image
```

by adding this line the new picture will be like this:

[image]

so what about resizing the image? there is a function in OpenCV which it's name is `cv2.resize` by that you can resize image to any size, I reshape your image to (100,200) in the below line and re-run the code:

```
image = cv2.resize(image,(100,200))
```

And the result will be:

[image]

The whole code will be like the below:

```
import os
#from colorthief import ColorThief
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

imgDirec = "/home/isv/Desktop/"

def find_dominant_color(filename):
        #Resizing parameters
        width, height = 150,150
        image = Image.open(filename)
        image = image.resize((width, height),resample = 0)
        #Get colors from image object
        pixels = image.getcolors(width * height)
        #Sort them by count number(first element of tuple)
        sorted_pixels = sorted(pixels, key=lambda t: t[0])
        #Get the most frequent color
        dominant_color = sorted_pixels[-1][1]
        return dominant_color





filepath = "/home/isv/Desktop/image.jpg" #Foreground Image
dominant_color = find_dominant_color(filepath)
#dominant_color = color_thief.get_color(quality=1)
print(dominant_color)
image = cv2.imread(filepath)
image = cv2.resize(image,(100,200))    #added line
image_copy = np.copy(image)
image_copy = cv2.cvtColor(image_copy, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
lower_blue = np.array([dominant_color[0]-20, dominant_color[1]-20, dominant_color[2]-20])     ##[R value, G value, B value]
upper_blue = np.array([dominant_color[0]+20, dominant_color[1]+20, dominant_color[2]+20])
#plt.imshow(image_copy)


mask = cv2.inRange(image_copy, lower_blue, upper_blue)
#plt.imshow(mask, cmap='gray')

masked_image = np.copy(image_copy)
masked_image[mask != 0] = [0, 0, 0]
#plt.imshow(masked_image)
background_image = cv2.imread('/home/isv/Desktop/background1.jpg')
background_image = cv2.cvtColor(background_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

x_offset=100    #added line
y_offset=200    #added line
crop_background = background_image[y_offset:image_copy.shape[0]+y_offset, x_offset:image_copy.shape[1]+x_offset]   #change line

crop_background[mask == 0] = [0, 0, 0]

#plt.imshow(crop_background)

#These Transformations do not work as intended.
newImg = cv2.resize(crop_background, (0,0), fx=2, fy=2)

height, width = masked_image.shape[:2]
quarter_height, quarter_width = height / 4, width / 4
T = np.float32([[1, 0, quarter_width], [0, 1, quarter_height]])
img_translation = cv2.warpAffine(masked_image, T, (width, height)) 


final_image = crop_background + masked_image
background_image[y_offset:image_copy.shape[0]+y_offset, x_offset:image_copy.shape[1]+x_offset]=final_image   #added line
plt.imshow(final_image)
plt.show()

plt.figure()                        # added line
plt.imshow(background_image)        # added line
plt.show()                          # added line
```

I hope that this code will help you.